# Which types of blood vessels can regenerate in humans/mammals?

Tags: human-biology, blood-circulation, physiology

Which types of blood vessels can regenerate in humans/mammals?
From what I understand, arteries and arterioles can be created later in life, while this is not necessarily the case with veins. However I don't understand why damaged blood vessels in an eye recover, while this is not the case for other body parts. Also, I don't understand how angiogenic agents work.

The types of blood vessels I've been thinking about include:

- Arteries
- Arterioles
- Capillaries
- Venules
- Veins

Also, does the capability vary in different organs (e.g. blood vessels in a hand vs blood vessels in an eye)?

Comment: Is this by chance a homework question? If so, please read our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). Essentially, we ask you to try and answer as much of the question yourself as you can, and put down your thinking on the parts you're not sure about.

Comment: @MattDMo - no, this is not a homework question. I did some research, and it seems that arteries and arterioles can be created later in life, while this is not necessarily the case with veins. However I don't understand why damaged blood vessels in an eye recover, while this is not the case for other body parts. I don't understand how angiogenic agents work. I mean I could spend a month researching the topic and reading every scientific article, but what is the point of this community?